# Apache 301 redirect Query String URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I want to redirect to one query string URL to another:

```
example.com/product-category/search/?filter_grade-level=154
```

to

```
example.com/product-category/search/?filter_grade-level=k
```

Any thoughts what to add in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite to check the query string. Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(filter_grade-level)=154$
RewriteRule ^product-category/search/$ /$0?%1=k [R=301,L]
```

In the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (ie. `/$0?%1=k`), `$0` is a backreference to the entire matched `RewriteRule` *pattern* and `%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* (ie. "filter_grade-level").

So, on success, `/$0?%1=k` expands to:

```
/product-category/search/?filter_grade-level=k
```